# AsyncTask taking long time to start Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

AM using AsyncTask to retrieve data from services. but it taking too much time i.e., about 2 mins or so ..

I found out that, when i start the asynctask the dialog show is showing but background process taking time to respond and getting data.

Check my code of asynctask:

```
 public class JamsTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Bundle> 
     { 


            private Context ctx; 
            ProgressDialog dlg;
            Bitmap userImage;
            String message ;

            public JamsTask(Context context) { 
                ctx = context; 
            } 

            @Override 
            protected void onPreExecute() { 
                //super.onPreExecute(); 
           try{
                dlg = new ProgressDialog(Jams.this); 
                dlg.setMessage("Please wait...."); 
                dlg.show();
           }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }


                //setContentView(R.layout.splash);
            } 


            @Override
            protected Bundle doInBackground(Void... params) {
                   Bundle b=new Bundle();



                try{

                 SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);



                 request.addProperty("fkPersonId", Integer.valueOf(JujamaMain.userValues.get(0)));
                 request.addProperty("fkConferenceId", Integer.valueOf(JujamaMain.userValues.get(4)));
                 request.addProperty("startIndex",1);
                 request.addProperty("endIndex",20);



                   SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                   envelope.dotNet=true;
                   envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

                   HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

                   androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

                   Object result= envelope.getResponse(); 

                   SoapObject response=(SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;



                  strRes = result.toString();





                  SoapObject returnObj = (SoapObject)response.getProperty("GetAllStatusUpdatesResult");

                  SoapObject object=(SoapObject) returnObj.getProperty(1);


                  SoapObject returnObj2 = (SoapObject)object.getProperty("NewDataSet");



                 // Integer id = Integer.valueOf(returnObj.getPropertySafelyAsString("id");


                  for(int i=0;i<returnObj2.getPropertyCount();i++) {
                      SoapObject persondetails = (SoapObject)returnObj2.getProperty(i);



                      String salution = (String)persondetails.getPropertySafelyAsString("Salutation","");
                      //String companyname = (String)persondetails.getPropertySafelyAsString("CompanyName");
                      String firstname = (String)persondetails.getPropertySafelyAsString("FirstName","");

                      String lastname = (String)persondetails.getPropertySafelyAsString("LastName","");



                     if(!persondetails.getPropertySafelyAsString("Message","").contains("anyType"))
                        message = (String)persondetails.getPropertySafelyAsString("Message","");
                     else
                         message=""
;                     
                      String nameID = (String)persondetails.getPropertySafelyAsString("PKStatusID","");




                      String fkconfid = (String)persondetails.getPropertySafelyAsString("FKConferenceID","");





                  try{   

                     SimpleDateFormat form = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
                      java.util.Date date = null;
                      String sub=commented.substring(0, 19);

                       date = form.parse(sub);


                      SimpleDateFormat postFormater =new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM dd, yyyy, HH:mm");
                      String newDateStr = postFormater.format(date);

                      mTimedifference.add(newDateStr);


                   /* DateTime myBirthDate = new DateTime(year,month, day, hour, minute, 0, 0);
                      DateTime now = new DateTime();
                      Period period = new Period(myBirthDate, now);

                      PeriodFormatter formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
                          .appendYears().appendSuffix(" years, ")
                          .appendMonths().appendSuffix(" months, ")
                          .appendWeeks().appendSuffix(" weeks, ")
                          .appendDays().appendSuffix(" days, ")
                          .appendHours().appendSuffix(" hours, ")
                          .appendMinutes().appendSuffix(" minutes, ")

                          .printZeroNever()
                          .toFormatter();

                      String elapsed = formatter.print(period);
                      System.out.println(elapsed + " ago");*/

                  }catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                      e.printStackTrace();

                }

                     // System.out.println(".."+"dat"+now+"..."+time);
                      mNameID.add(nameID);


                      String ImageUrl = (String)persondetails.getPropertySafelyAsString("PhotoGuid","");

                      String liked = (String)persondetails.getPropertySafelyAsString("Liked","No");
                      String nocomments = (String)persondetails.getPropertySafelyAsString("NoofComments","0");

                      mName.add(firstname.toString()+lastname.toString()+salution.toString());
                      mMessages.add(message.toString());
                      mLikesCount.add(likescount.toString());



                         mLikeText.add(liked);
                         mNoComments.add(nocomments);




                         userImage=getBitmapFromURL("http://test.jujama.com/uploadfiles/"+ImageUrl);

                      Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.nophoto);

                      if(userImage==null)
                             mUserImage.add(bmp);
                         else
                          mUserImage.add(userImage);


                  }




                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

                return b;
            }    





              @Override 
                protected void onPostExecute(Bundle b) { 

                 dlg.dismiss(); 

                 lv.setAdapter(new Viewadapter(Jams.this));





              }

         }
```

Is there any way to reduce the time . because its too much time.

and one more:

bfore it starts:this below types of lines are coming .

```
 GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 31921 objects / 2006888 bytes in 100ms
```

Thanks

Comment: are you closing the dialog in post execute?,just asking, because i don't see that in the code you posted

Comment: dlg.dismiss() is the code for closing dialog..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is hard to tell why from looking at your code why it is so slow. The best guess would be that you are, I believe, doing two web requests (once of which is fetching an image). It could be that your services are just very slow.

The log lines you posted above mean you are allocating memory.  If you are doing something memory intensive you can expect to see a lot of them.

It is also possible that you have a lot of other threads going and the AsyncTask thread has lower priority than the other threads and is then essentially blocked by them. Try raising its priority (no idea how to do) or carefully look at the other threads in your code.

Comment: Yeah the thing fetching image is taking time.. can u suggest any better way to handle this image fetching and webservice

Comment: You can check if your thread is waiting on Android Developer Studio/Debug/Threads